# One boot menu for two OS on two separate hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, operating-systems, bootloader

So here's the hypothetical situation. I have two Solid State Drives, both 250gb. I'm wanting to install windows 7/10 on one of these drives, as well as Linux Fedora Workstation on the other. Ideally, I'd like to be able boot into both operating systems without having to go through my BIOS and alter the boot order of my drives.

So, generally speaking, I want to create a boot loader/manager on one drive (the windows 7/10 drive) that would appear before I load into the operating system, which would have options to boot into either of the operating systems located on the two drives. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

When I did this, linux picked up the windows partition automatically. Just install them on different drives and each will have its own bootloader

Just install windows first, then linux (or add the windows partition manually if you must/rebuild grub config with `update grub`/update the grub package so it rebuilds grub config) and choose the linux partition higher up in the boot order.

It should be trivial to get this working